# How do i convert date time format in informatica

Tags: sql, informatica

I want to map a datetime `mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` attribute in flatfile to Teradata table date `yyyy-mm-dd` attribute using informatica.

When I added `to_date(date_field, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` I'm encountering oracle fatal error. When I tried with `to_date(to_char(date_field, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))` it is giving **invalid string input** to `to_date()`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: if your date_field came with the format you said, just do this: `to_date(to_char(date_field, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:mi:ss'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Informatica, the format that you specify under `to_date()` function should be same as your source data format and **not** your target format.

So in your case, to_date function should be like this:

```
to_date (date_field, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

This is because your flat file date has a format of `mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` (Ensure that all the records in this column in your flat file date are really in this format - else you will encounter error)

Do not worry about target date format as long as the target column is a `date` datatype. By nature, `date` datatype does not have a format, it's only the display that needs format.